# laravel get the authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When the user login, I do the following:

```
 $remember_me = true;
        if(Input::has('remember_me')){
            $remember_me = true;
        }else{
            $remember_me = false;
        }

        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')), $remember_me))
        {
            echo Auth::user()->picture;exit;
        }
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors(Input::all())->with(array('errorMessage'=>'Username or password is not correct'));
```

and as you see, I am printing the value of the picture and it is correct. so the user has signed in and I should be able to call him/her like this in another controller

```
$user = Auth::user();
echo $user->firstName;exit
```

but I get :

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I already set the remember me to true. what should I do to be able to use the authenticated user please?

many thanks

Comment: Dont ever `exit` - you should *always* return something in Laravel so the headers are correctly set.

Comment: And its probably a session error perhaps...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange okay I will try to redirect to the route that is calling the $user->firstName and update you

Comment: @TheShiftExchange excellent, it works, why does exit` cause that problem please? just to understand what is going on

Comment: @TheShiftExchange write an answer to accept it please. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should never `exit` a function in Laravel.
- It is important you always `return` something.

The reason is Laravel handles some of the final implementation of your functions, set as setting headers, cookies etc. When you `exit`, you short circuit this process, so Laravel cant finish some of its functions, and therefore you will get errors.

Comment: could you check my question please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476541/laravel-couldnt-generate-a-good-route Thanks in advance