# Update route generates incorrect url

Tags: php, laravel-4, restful-url, laravel-routing

This is my html blade code

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'restaurants.update', 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer')) }}

<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Website</label>
        <div class="oneInfo">
            <input type="text" value="{{$restaurant->website}}" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
        <input type="button" value="Cancle" class="cancelButton"/>
    </li>
</ul>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

But the url for the form is : `public/restaurants/%7Brestaurants%7D`

Thought I already have the route:

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

Comment: `%7B` and `%7D` are `{` and `}` respectively

Comment: @MarkBaker what do they appear? I didn't write them

Comment: `'route' => 'restaurants.update'` but `Route::resource('admins', 'AdminsController');` ???

Comment: @Unnawut that was a type sorry, I missed up because I am trying like a million solutions but nothing works. help please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Mark Baker said %7B and %7D are { and } respectively , laravel expect you to pass the id of the resource you want to update.

If you see the [board](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) with the action you will notice that you have to pass the resource id.

```
PUT/PATCH   /resource/{resource}    update  resource.update
```

You can use the `route` helper function to fix it.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => route('restaurants.update', $restaurant->id), 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer')) }}
```

Comment: when I did this `
{{Form::open(array('route'=>array('restaurants.update', $restaurant->id), 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer')) }}` , the url goes to `restaurants/20` not to the `update` function why please?

Comment: I tried to add medtho post but the same, goes to `restaurant/20` not to the udpate

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent It's `'route' => route('restaurants.update'` not `'route' => array('restaurants.update'`, from what giannis said.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent Your URL is correct, preferably use the first way I saw you cause some broswer doesn't support PUT/PATCH so laravel spoof it adding an extra hidden field with the method type.

Comment: when I do this: `{{Form::open(array('route'=>route('restaurants.update', $restaurant->id), 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer', 'method' => 'PUT')) }}` the page that has the form is not opening. I got `route: restaurant/20 ` is not defined

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent `{{Form::open(array('route'=> route('restaurants.update', $restaurant->id), 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer')) }}`

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent I had the same problem - changing the 'route' => route to be 'route' => array fixed it for me. `{{Form::open(array('route'=>array('restaurants.update', $restaurant->id), 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer', 'method' => 'PUT')) }}`